# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor returning even though file closed using .close()

Tags: python, file, errno, oserror

I am currently trying out my hand at writing and reading from files.
Here is the problematic part of the code :

```
def ldi(regAdress, value):
    buffer = open(regAdress, "w")
    buffer.write(bin(value))
    buffer.close()
def rdi(regAdress):
    buffer = open(regAdress, "r")
    print(int(buffer.read(10)))
    buffer.close()
```

As you can see, the first function properly closes to file before ending. However, when the second is called, it returns the previously mentionned error. I read that this was meant to me that the file was still open, and that my program was trying to open it again, causing an error.

TL;DR : Why is it still returning this error even though the file is closed ?

I tried putting the function contents inside of a try, finally block, with the first two lines of each inside of the try, and the final inside the finally, but it simply returns that "buffer" was referenced before assignement.

Comment: How much time passes between `ldi` returning and `rid` being called?

Comment: Can you give the full traceback of your exception? Because I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code you've shown (though using a `with` statement would be more elegant).

Comment: @ScottHunter they are called in following if statements in this scenario, so not much time

Comment: @Blckknght 0b1Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alaric/Desktop/python projects for portfolio/SHL/interpreter.py", line 30, in <module>
    rdi(int(instructionBuffer[1]))
  File "/home/alaric/Desktop/python projects for portfolio/SHL/interpreter.py", line 13, in rdi
    buffer = open(regAdress, "r")
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor EDIT : the "ob1" is simply because I am reading an writing in binary (no particular reason, and the same error occurs with integers)

Comment: I believe the problem is because `regAddress` is an integer, not a string filename.